# How to add tags into view side by side by button click using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create `tags` UI side by side. The tags should be increment upto five by button click. I tried by using `horizontal` `stacklayout` with multiple `buttons` but its not working properly. How to achieve below UI, Provide some idea.

My `storyboard` below with horizontal stacklayout and its `attributes`

## Storyboard

[image: Storyboard]

## Horizontal Stacklayout Attributes

[image: Horizontal Stacklayout Attributes]

## Expected output

[image: Expected output]

Comment: I think what would work best for this type of UI would be a horizontal collectionView. And use the delegate functions to know when any given cell was selected similar to a button.

Comment: What do you mean by working not properly?